# OrangeHRM modification with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: orangehrm

I need help in creating another page and modify some pages (adding and deleting some fields) in **OrangeHRM**. I have a little knowledge in Symfony 1.4. Can anyone give me a step by step procedures to achieve this? No need to mention the codes just the procedure like what files need to be edited and what command to execute in Command prompt. I'm using windows.
Please I need help with this because I'm making this for a big enough company. Thanks in advance and any help will be app

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what kind of changes you need to make or what module you want to modify as that is needed if you want to know the files involved.

The below links would help you in starting off with the OrangeHRM codebase and Symfony plugin development/modification.

http://wiki.orangehrm.com/ohrmwiki/index.php/Orange_Developer_Wiki

http://wiki.orangehrm.com/ohrmwiki/index.php/Developing_With_Symfony

http://wiki.orangehrm.com/ohrmwiki/index.php/Developing_Symfony_Plugins

Comment: these linkk not working any idea?